# Provide access to another user on EC2 instance.

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

A friend of mine, wants me to access his ec2 instance.

He does not want to share his secret file.

I advised him to put my public ssh keys, in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys of his ec2 instance.

If the key is of the following format -

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ.........yjENBExpe6CJ4vUJzHQ0K62cmJW4iduIJ82Om8JCJ2eNgnmS3TP9WSZueFTbvao3YdVZkGBLOciA/aXoCn3 *******@ya**o.co.in

If he puts this under the ssh keys, will I be able to login?

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is the **best** way to do it.